# Select * but no results containing "This"

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way in sql to write a query that returns all results other than ones containing "This"

So in my mind it would look something like this but I know it doesn't work

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename EXCLUDING WHERE col1 = This'
```

I know the above won't work, but is there something similar that will, can't seem to find anything on here to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `NOT LIKE`:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col1 NOT LIKE "%This%"'
```

From [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-like.php):

> MySQL NOT LIKE is used to exclude those rows which are matching the criterion followed by LIKE operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col1 not like "%This%"'
```

or if col1 takes exact values

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col1 !="This"'
```

Comment: Thanks working. would mark correct but someone got in before you

Comment: @Lewis No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_name where col1 not like '%This%';
```

Comment: Thanks working. would mark correct but someone got in before you